# A standard-conforming C++17 std::optional implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, stl

I took quite some time to implement a fully standard-conforming `std::optional` in C++17.  It turns out more sophisticated than I initially thought.  My code is just below 1000 lines (excluding empty lines), and I have tested the functions extensively.

There have been some attempts to implement `std::optional` on Code Review.  A simple [search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Breinventing-the-wheel%5D+optional+is%3Aquestion) brings up two:

- [Reinventing std::optional](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158311) - far from standard conforming;
- [`std::optional` under C++14 v1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216669) - nice in general, but doesn't implement the interaction between `constexpr` and triviality correctly.

Some facts that complicate the implementation:

- Many operations are `constexpr` friendly.  With `constexpr`, the `aligned_storage` + explicit construction / destruction technique becomes useless.  The standard is effectively asking us to use a union.  The fact that the `constexpr`-ness on the copy / move operations depends on the triviality of the corresponding operations on the value type is a clear evidence because that's exactly how unions work.
- The special member functions conditionally get defined as deleted / participate in overload resolution.  Since special member functions cannot be templates, SFINAE cannot be used, and the only way to implement this that I can think of is to write a chain of base classes and use class template specialization, and then use `= default` to "inherit" the (possibly deleted) special member functions.

I used [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659) (C++17 final draft) as a reference.  The relevant parts are [[optional]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional), [[unord.hash]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.hash), and [[depr.func.adaptor.binding]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/depr.func.adaptor.binding) (for the deprecated `std::hash<...>::result_type` and `std::hash<...>::argument_type`).

Except for `std::hash`, all functionalities are provided in the `my_std` namespace. As you can see, basically everything is boilerplate code and the actual code is almost zero.

```
// C++17 std::optional implementation

#ifndef INC_OPTIONAL_HPP_9AEkHPjv56
#define INC_OPTIONAL_HPP_9AEkHPjv56

#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>    // for std::destroy_at
#include <typeindex> // for std::hash
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace my_std {

    // [optional.optional], class template optional
    template <class T>
    class optional;

    // [utility.syn], [in-place construction]
    struct in_place_t {
        explicit in_place_t() = default;
    };
    inline constexpr in_place_t in_place{};

    // [optional.nullopt], no-value state indicator
    struct nullopt_t {
        constexpr explicit nullopt_t(int) {}
    };
    inline constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{0};

    // [optional.bad.access], class bad_optional_access
    class bad_optional_access :public std::exception {
    public:
        bad_optional_access() = default;
    };

    // [optional.relops], relational operators
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>&, const optional<U>&);

    // [optional.nullops], comparison with nullopt
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator==(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;

    // [optional.comp.with.t], comparison with T
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const U&, const optional<T>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const U&, const optional<T>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const U&, const optional<T>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const U&, const optional<T>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const U&, const optional<T>&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>&, const U&);
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const U&, const optional<T>&);

    // [optional.specalg], specialized algorithms
    template <class T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_move_constructible_v<T> && std::is_swappable_v<T>>
        swap(optional<T>& x, optional<T>& y) noexcept(noexcept(x.swap(y)))
    {
        x.swap(y);
    }

    template <class T>
    constexpr optional<std::decay_t<T>> make_optional(T&& v)
    {
        return optional<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(v));
    }
    template <class T, class... Args>
    constexpr optional<T> make_optional(Args&&... args)
    {
        return optional<T>(in_place, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <class T, class U, class... Args>
    constexpr optional<T> make_optional(std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args)
    {
        return optional<T>(in_place, il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

}

namespace std {

    // [optional.hash], hash support
    template <class T>
    struct hash<my_std::optional<T>>;

}

namespace my_std::detail {
    template <class T, class U>
    struct is_cv_same :std::is_same<
        std::remove_const_t<std::remove_volatile_t<T>>,
        std::remove_const_t<std::remove_volatile_t<U>>
        > { };
    template <class T, class U>
    inline constexpr bool is_cv_same_v = is_cv_same<T, U>::value;

    template <class T>
    struct enable {
        // constructors
        template <class... Args>
        using in_place = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using conv_implicit =
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U&&> &&
                             !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, in_place_t> &&
                             !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, optional<T>> &&
                             std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using conv_explicit =
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U&&> &&
                             !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, in_place_t> &&
                             !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, optional<T>> &&
                             !std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, int>;
        template <class U>
        static constexpr bool conv_common =
            !std::is_constructible_v<T,       optional<U>& > &&
            !std::is_constructible_v<T,       optional<U>&&> &&
            !std::is_constructible_v<T, const optional<U>& > &&
            !std::is_constructible_v<T, const optional<U>&&> &&
            !std::is_convertible_v<      optional<U>& , T> &&
            !std::is_convertible_v<      optional<U>&&, T> &&
            !std::is_convertible_v<const optional<U>& , T> &&
            !std::is_convertible_v<const optional<U>&&, T>;
        template <class U>
        using copy_conv_implicit =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&> &&
                             std::is_convertible_v<const U&, T>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using copy_conv_explicit =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&> &&
                             !std::is_convertible_v<const U&, T>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using move_conv_implicit =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, U&&> &&
                             std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using move_conv_explicit =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, U&&> &&
                             !std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, int>;

        // assignment
        template <class U>
        using conv_ass =
            std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<optional<T>, std::decay_t<U>> &&
                             !(std::is_scalar_v<T> &&
                               std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<U>>) &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, U> &&
                             std::is_assignable_v<T&, U>, int>;
        template <class U>
        static constexpr bool conv_ass_common = conv_common<U> &&
            !std::is_assignable_v<T&,       optional<U>& > &&
            !std::is_assignable_v<T&, const optional<U>& > &&
            !std::is_assignable_v<T&,       optional<U>&&> &&
            !std::is_assignable_v<T&, const optional<U>&&>;
        template <class U>
        using copy_conv_ass =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_ass_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&> &&
                             std::is_assignable_v<T&, const U&>, int>;
        template <class U>
        using move_conv_ass =
            std::enable_if_t<conv_ass_common<U> &&
                             std::is_constructible_v<T, U> &&
                             std::is_assignable_v<T&, U>, int>;

        // emplace
        template <class U, class... Args>
        using emplace_ilist =
            std::enable_if_t<
                std::is_constructible_v<T, std::initializer_list<U>, Args...>
                , int>;
    };

    // deal with destructor
    // trivially destructible version
    template <class T, bool = std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>>
    class destroy_base {
        static_assert(std::is_object_v<T>, "[optional.optional]/3");
        static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<T>, "[optional.optional]/3");
        static_assert(!detail::is_cv_same_v<T, in_place_t>, "[optional.syn]/1");
        static_assert(!detail::is_cv_same_v<T, nullopt_t>,  "[optional.syn]/1");
    public:
        constexpr destroy_base() noexcept {}
        ~destroy_base() = default;
        constexpr destroy_base(const destroy_base& rhs) = default;
        constexpr destroy_base(destroy_base&& rhs) = default;
        destroy_base& operator=(const destroy_base& rhs) = default;
        destroy_base& operator=(destroy_base&& rhs) = default;

        constexpr destroy_base(nullopt_t) noexcept {}
        template <class... Args,
                  typename enable<T>::template in_place<Args...> = 0>
        constexpr explicit destroy_base(in_place_t, Args&&... args)
            :object(std::forward<Args>(args)...), contains{true}
        {
        }
        template <class U, class... Args,
                  typename enable<T>::template in_place<std::initializer_list<U>&,
                                                        Args...> = 0>
        constexpr explicit destroy_base(in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> ilist,
                                        Args&&... args)
            :object(ilist, std::forward<Args>(args)...), contains{true}
        {
        }

        constexpr bool has_value() const noexcept
        {
            return contains;
        }
        void reset() noexcept
        {
            destroy();
        }

    protected:
        constexpr T* get() noexcept
        {
            return &object;
        }
        constexpr const T* get() const noexcept
        {
            return &object;
        }
        template <typename... Args>
        void construct(Args&&... args)
        {
            assert(!has_value());
            ::new (get()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            contains = true;
        }
        void destroy() noexcept
        {
            assert(has_value());
            contains = false;
        }

    private:
        union {
            char dummy{'\0'};
            T object;
        };
        bool contains{false};
    };

    // non-trivially destructible version
    template <class T>
    class destroy_base<T, false> {
        static_assert(std::is_object_v<T>, "[optional.optional]/3");
        static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<T>, "[optional.optional]/3");
        static_assert(!detail::is_cv_same_v<T, in_place_t>, "[optional.syn]/1");
        static_assert(!detail::is_cv_same_v<T, nullopt_t>,  "[optional.syn]/1");
    public:
        constexpr destroy_base() noexcept {}
        constexpr destroy_base(const destroy_base& rhs) = default;
        constexpr destroy_base(destroy_base&& rhs) = default;
        destroy_base& operator=(const destroy_base& rhs) = default;
        destroy_base& operator=(destroy_base&& rhs) = default;

        ~destroy_base()
        {
            reset();
        }

        constexpr destroy_base(nullopt_t) noexcept {}
        template <class... Args,
                  typename enable<T>::template in_place<Args...> = 0>
        constexpr explicit destroy_base(in_place_t, Args&&... args)
            :object(std::forward<Args>(args)...), contains{true}
        {
        }
        template <class U, class... Args,
                  typename enable<T>::template in_place<std::initializer_list<U>&,
                                                        Args...> = 0>
        constexpr explicit destroy_base(in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> ilist,
                                        Args&&... args)
            :object(ilist, std::forward<Args>(args)...), contains{true}
        {
        }

        constexpr bool has_value() const noexcept
        {
            return contains;
        }
        void reset() noexcept
        {
            if (has_value())
                destroy();
        }

    protected:
        constexpr T* get() noexcept
        {
            return &object;
        }
        constexpr const T* get() const noexcept
        {
            return &object;
        }
        template <typename... Args>
        void construct(Args&&... args)
        {
            assert(!has_value());
            ::new (get()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            contains = true;
        }
        void destroy() noexcept
        {
            assert(has_value());
            std::destroy_at(get());
            contains = false;
        }

    private:
        union {
            char dummy{'\0'};
            T object;
        };
        bool contains{false};        
    };

    template <class T>
    class common_base :public destroy_base<T> {
    public:
        using destroy_base<T>::destroy_base;

        constexpr common_base() = default;
        constexpr common_base(const common_base&) = default;
        constexpr common_base(common_base&&) = default;
        common_base& operator=(const common_base&) = default;
        common_base& operator=(common_base&&) = default;

        constexpr T* operator->()
        {
            assert(*this);
            return this->get();
        }
        constexpr const T* operator->() const
        {
            assert(*this);
            return this->get();
        }

        constexpr T& operator*() &
        {
            assert(*this);
            return *this->get();
        }
        constexpr const T& operator*() const &
        {
            assert(*this);
            return *this->get();
        }
        constexpr T&& operator*() &&
        {
            return std::move(*this->get());
        }
        constexpr const T&& operator*() const &&
        {
            return std::move(*this->get());
        }

        constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept
        {
            return this->has_value();
        }

    protected:
        // assign if has value, construct otherwise
        template <typename U>
        void assign(U&& arg)
        {
            if (this->has_value())
                **this = std::forward<U>(arg);
            else
                this->construct(std::forward<U>(arg));
        }
    };

    // deal with copy constructor
    // trivially copy constructible version
    template <class T, bool = std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>,
              bool = std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>>
    class copy_construct_base :public common_base<T> {
        using Base = common_base<T>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;

        constexpr copy_construct_base() = default;
        constexpr copy_construct_base(const copy_construct_base& rhs) = default;
        constexpr copy_construct_base(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(const copy_construct_base&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // non-trivially copy constructible version
    template <class T>
    class copy_construct_base<T, true, false> :public common_base<T> {
    public:
        using common_base<T>::common_base;

        constexpr copy_construct_base() = default;
        copy_construct_base(const copy_construct_base& rhs) // not constexpr
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(*rhs);
        }
        constexpr copy_construct_base(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(const copy_construct_base&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // non-copy constructible version
    template <class T>
    class copy_construct_base<T, false, false> :public common_base<T> {
    public:
        using common_base<T>::common_base;

        constexpr copy_construct_base() = default;
        copy_construct_base(const copy_construct_base&) = delete;
        constexpr copy_construct_base(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(const copy_construct_base&) = default;
        copy_construct_base& operator=(copy_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // deal with move constructor
    // trivially move constructible version
    template <class T, bool = std::is_move_constructible_v<T>,
              bool = std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>>
    class move_construct_base :public copy_construct_base<T> {
        using Base = copy_construct_base<T>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;

        constexpr move_construct_base() = default;
        constexpr move_construct_base(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        constexpr move_construct_base(move_construct_base&& rhs)
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) = default;
        move_construct_base& operator=(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        move_construct_base& operator=(move_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // non-trivially move constructible version
    template <class T>
    class move_construct_base<T, true, false> :public copy_construct_base<T> {
    public:
        using copy_construct_base<T>::copy_construct_base;

        constexpr move_construct_base() = default; 
        constexpr move_construct_base(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        move_construct_base(move_construct_base&& rhs) // not constexpr
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(std::move(*rhs));
        }
        move_construct_base& operator=(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        move_construct_base& operator=(move_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // non-move constructible version
    template <class T>
    class move_construct_base<T, false, false> :public copy_construct_base<T> {
    public:
        using copy_construct_base<T>::copy_construct_base;

        constexpr move_construct_base() = default; 
        constexpr move_construct_base(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        move_construct_base(move_construct_base&& rhs) = delete;
        move_construct_base& operator=(const move_construct_base&) = default;
        move_construct_base& operator=(move_construct_base&&) = default;
    };

    // deal with copy assignment
    // copy constructible and assignable version
    template <class T, bool = (std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> &&
                               std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>)>
    class copy_assign_base :public move_construct_base<T> {
        using Base = move_construct_base<T>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;

        constexpr copy_assign_base() = default;
        constexpr copy_assign_base(const copy_assign_base&) = default;
        constexpr copy_assign_base(copy_assign_base&&) = default;
        copy_assign_base& operator=(const copy_assign_base& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->assign(*rhs);
            else
                this->reset();
            return *this;
        }
        copy_assign_base& operator=(copy_assign_base&&) = default;
    };

    // non-(copy constructible and assignable) version
    template <class T>
    class copy_assign_base<T, false> :public move_construct_base<T> {
    public:
        using move_construct_base<T>::move_construct_base;

        constexpr copy_assign_base() = default;
        constexpr copy_assign_base(const copy_assign_base&) = default;
        constexpr copy_assign_base(copy_assign_base&&) = default;
        copy_assign_base& operator=(const copy_assign_base&) = delete;
        copy_assign_base& operator=(copy_assign_base&&) = default;
    };

    // deal with move assignment
    // move constructible and assignable version
    template <class T, bool = (std::is_move_constructible_v<T> &&
                               std::is_move_assignable_v<T>)>
    class move_assign_base :public copy_assign_base<T> {
        using Base = copy_assign_base<T>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;

        constexpr move_assign_base() = default;
        constexpr move_assign_base(const move_assign_base&) = default;
        constexpr move_assign_base(move_assign_base&&) = default;
        move_assign_base& operator=(const move_assign_base&) = default;
        move_assign_base& operator=(move_assign_base&& rhs)
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T> &&
                     std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->assign(std::move(*rhs));
            else
                this->reset();
            return *this;
        }
    };

    // non-(move constructible and assignable) version
    template <class T>
    class move_assign_base<T, false> :public copy_assign_base<T> {
    public:
        using copy_assign_base<T>::copy_assign_base;

        constexpr move_assign_base() = default;
        constexpr move_assign_base(const move_assign_base&) = default;
        constexpr move_assign_base(move_assign_base&&) = default;
        move_assign_base& operator=(const move_assign_base&) = default;
        move_assign_base& operator=(move_assign_base&&) = delete;
    };
}

namespace my_std {

    template <class T>
    class optional :public detail::move_assign_base<T> {
        using Base = detail::move_assign_base<T>;
        using Enable = detail::enable<T>;

    public:
        using value_type = T;

        using Base::Base;

        optional() = default;
        ~optional() = default;
        optional(const optional&) = default;
        optional(optional&&) = default;
        optional& operator=(const optional&) = default;
        optional& operator=(optional&&) = default;

        template <class U = T,
                  typename Enable::template conv_implicit<U> = 0>
        constexpr optional(U&& v)
            :Base{in_place, std::forward<U>(v)}
        {
        }
        template <class U = T,
                  typename Enable::template conv_explicit<U> = 0>
        explicit constexpr optional(U&& v)
            :Base{in_place, std::forward<U>(v)}
        {
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template copy_conv_implicit<U> = 0>
        optional(const optional<U>& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(*rhs);
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template copy_conv_explicit<U> = 0>
        explicit optional(const optional<U>& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(*rhs);
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template move_conv_implicit<U> = 0>
        optional(optional<U>&& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(std::move(*rhs));
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template move_conv_explicit<U> = 0>
        explicit optional(optional<U>&& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->construct(std::move(*rhs));
        }

        optional& operator=(nullopt_t) noexcept
        {
            this->reset();
            return *this;
        }
        template <class U = T,
                  typename Enable::template conv_ass<U> = 0>
        optional& operator=(U&& v)
        {
            this->assign(std::forward<U>(v));
            return *this;
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template copy_conv_ass<U> = 0>
        optional& operator=(const optional<U>& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->assign(*rhs);
            else
                this->reset();
            return *this;
        }
        template <class U,
                  typename Enable::template move_conv_ass<U> = 0>
        optional& operator=(optional<U>&& rhs)
        {
            if (rhs)
                this->assign(std::move(*rhs));
            else
                this->reset();
            return *this;
        }

        template <class... Args>
        T& emplace(Args&&... args)
        {
            static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>,
                          "[optional.assign]/25");
            this->reset();
            this->construct(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return **this;
        }
        template <class U, class... Args,
                  typename Enable::template emplace_ilist<U, Args...> = 0>
        T& emplace(std::initializer_list<U> ilist, Args&&... args)
        {
            this->reset();
            this->construct(ilist, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return **this;
        }

        void swap(optional& rhs)
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T> &&
                     std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<T>)
        {
            if (*this && rhs) {
                using std::swap;
                swap(**this, *rhs);
            } else if (*this) {
                rhs.construct(std::move(**this));
                this->destroy();
            } else if (rhs) {
                this->construct(std::move(*rhs));
                rhs.destroy();
            }
        }

        constexpr T& value() &
        {
            if (*this)
                return **this;
            else
                throw bad_optional_access{};
        }
        constexpr const T& value() const &
        {
            if (*this)
                return **this;
            else
                throw bad_optional_access{};
        }
        constexpr T&& value() &&
        {
            if (*this)
                return std::move(**this);
            else
                throw bad_optional_access{};
        }
        constexpr const T&& value() const &&
        {
            if (*this)
                return std::move(**this);
            else
                throw bad_optional_access{};
        }

        template <class U>
        constexpr T value_or(U&& v) const &
        {
            static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>, "[optional.observe]/18");
            static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, "[optional.observe]/18");

            if (*this)
                return **this;
            else
                return static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(v));
        }
        template <class U>
        constexpr T value_or(U&& v) &&
        {
            static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<T>, "[optional.observe]/20");
            static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>, "[optional.observe]/20");

            if (*this)
                return std::move(**this);
            else
                return static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(v));
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    optional(T) -> optional<T>;

    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return y && static_cast<bool>(*x == *y);
        else
            return !y;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return !y || static_cast<bool>(*x != *y);
        else
            return static_cast<bool>(y);
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return y && static_cast<bool>(*x < *y);
        else
            return static_cast<bool>(y);
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return !y || static_cast<bool>(*x > *y);
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return y && static_cast<bool>(*x <= *y);
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>& x, const optional<U>& y)
    {
        if (x)
            return !y || static_cast<bool>(*x >= *y);
        else
            return !y;
    }

    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>& x, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return !x;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator==(nullopt_t, const optional<T>& x) noexcept
    {
        return !x;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>& x, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(x);
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>& x) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(x);
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<(nullopt_t, const optional<T>& x) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(x);
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>& x, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return !x;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator<=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>& x, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(x);
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr bool operator>=(nullopt_t, const optional<T>& x) noexcept
    {
        return !x;
    }

    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x == v;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v == *x;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x != v;
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator!=(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v != *x;
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x < v;
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v < *x;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x <= v;
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator<=(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v <= *x;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x > v;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v > *x;
        else
            return true;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const optional<T>& x, const U& v)
    {
        if (x)
            return *x >= v;
        else
            return false;
    }
    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr bool operator>=(const U& v, const optional<T>& x)
    {
        if (x)
            return v >= *x;
        else
            return true;
    }

}

namespace my_std::detail {

    template <typename T>
    struct hash_is_enabled
        :std::is_default_constructible<std::hash<std::remove_const_t<T>>> {};
    template <typename T>
    inline constexpr bool hash_is_enabled_v = hash_is_enabled<T>::value;

    template <typename T>
    struct optional_hash {
        using result_type [[deprecated]] = std::size_t;
        using argument_type [[deprecated]] = my_std::optional<T>;

        constexpr std::size_t operator()(const optional<T>& o)
        {
            if (o)
                return std::hash<std::remove_const_t<T>>{}(*o);
            else
                return typeid(T).hash_code();
        }
    };

    struct disabled_hash {
        disabled_hash() = delete;
        disabled_hash(const disabled_hash&) = delete;
        disabled_hash& operator=(const disabled_hash&) = delete;
        disabled_hash(disabled_hash&&) = delete;
        disabled_hash& operator=(disabled_hash&&) = delete;
    };

}

namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    struct hash<my_std::optional<T>>
        :std::conditional_t<my_std::detail::hash_is_enabled_v<T>,
                            my_std::detail::optional_hash<T>,
                            my_std::detail::disabled_hash> {};
}

#endif
```

Here's the test if you want to see.  It's a bit unorganized, and not the most important part :)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "optional.hpp"

using namespace my_std;

struct Disabled {
    Disabled() = delete;
    Disabled(const Disabled&) = delete;
    Disabled& operator=(const Disabled&) = delete;
    Disabled(Disabled&&) = delete;
    Disabled& operator=(Disabled&&) = delete;
    ~Disabled() = default;
};

struct Nontrivial_copy {
    Nontrivial_copy() = default;
    Nontrivial_copy(const Nontrivial_copy&) {}
    Nontrivial_copy& operator=(const Nontrivial_copy&) = delete;
};

template <bool Noexcept = true>
struct Moveonly {
    Moveonly() = default;
    Moveonly(const Moveonly&) = delete;
    Moveonly& operator=(const Moveonly&) = delete;
    Moveonly(Moveonly&&) noexcept(Noexcept) {}
    Moveonly& operator=(Moveonly&&) noexcept(Noexcept) {}
};

struct Direct_init {
    // strict pattern
    constexpr Direct_init(int&, int&&) {}

    // no braced init
    template <class U>
    Direct_init(std::initializer_list<U>) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    // ill formed instantiation
    {
        // optional<int&> a;
        // optional<const in_place_t> b;
        // optional<volatile nullopt_t> c;
    }
    // value_type
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<optional<int>::value_type, int>);
    }
    // deduction guide
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<optional<int>, decltype(optional{42})>);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<optional<Moveonly<>>,
                      decltype(optional{Moveonly<>{}})>);
    }
    // default / nullopt constructor
    {
        constexpr optional<int> a{};
        constexpr optional<int> b = nullopt;
        static_assert(!a);
        static_assert(!b);
        constexpr optional<Disabled> c{};
        constexpr optional<Disabled> d = nullopt;
        static_assert(!c);
        static_assert(!d);

        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<optional<Disabled>>);
        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<optional<int>, nullopt_t>);
    }
    // trivial (constexpr) copy constructor
    {
        constexpr optional<int> a{};
        constexpr auto b = a;
        static_assert(!a && !b);
        constexpr optional c{42};
        constexpr auto d = c;
        static_assert(c == 42 && d == 42);
    }
    // non-trivial (non-constexpr) copy constructor
    {
        constexpr optional<Nontrivial_copy> a{};
        constexpr optional<Nontrivial_copy> b{in_place};
        /* constexpr */ auto c = a;
        /* constexpr */ auto d = b;
        assert(!c);
        assert(d);
    }
    // deleted copy constructor
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<optional<Disabled>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<optional<Moveonly<>>>);
    }
    // move constructor
    {
        optional<Moveonly<true>> a{};
        auto b = std::move(a);
        assert(!a);
        assert(!b);
        optional<Moveonly<false>> c{in_place};
        auto d = std::move(c);
        assert(c);
        assert(d);
    }
    // move constructor noexcept specification
    {
        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Moveonly<true>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Moveonly<false>>);
    }
    // deleted move constructor
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_move_constructible_v<optional<Disabled>>);
    }
    // in place constructor
    {
        int x = 21;
        constexpr optional<Direct_init> a{in_place, x, 42};
        static_assert(a);
    }
    // in place initializer list constructor
    {
        optional<std::vector<int>> b{in_place, {30, 36, 39, 42, 45}};
        assert((b == std::vector<int>{30, 36, 39, 42, 45}));
    }
    // in place constructor explicit
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<in_place_t, optional<Direct_init>>);
    }
    // single value constructor
    {
        optional<std::vector<int>> a{5}; // => std::vector<int>(5)
        assert(a->size() == 5);          // not 1
        constexpr optional<double> b = 42;
        static_assert(b == 42.0);
    }
    // explicit
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<const char*, optional<std::string>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<std::size_t,
                      optional<std::vector<int>>>);
    }
    // copying converting constructor
    {
        optional<int> a{5};
        optional<double> b = a;
        optional<std::vector<int>> v{a}; // => std::vector<int>(5)
        assert(b == 5);
        assert(v->size() == 5);          // not 1
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<const optional<int>&,
                                            optional<double>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<const optional<int>&,
                                             optional<std::vector<int>>>);
        optional<int> c{};
        optional<double> d = c;
        optional<std::vector<int>> w{c};
        assert(!d && !w);
    }
    // moving converting constructor
    {
        optional<int> a{5};
        optional<double> b = std::move(a);
        optional<std::vector<int>> v{std::move(a)};
        assert(a == 5 && b == 5 && v->size() == 5);
        static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<optional<int>&&,
                                             optional<std::vector<int>>>);
    }
    // destructor
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<optional<Disabled>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<optional<std::string>>);
    }
    // nullopt assignment
    {
        optional<std::vector<std::string>> a{in_place, 5, "foo"};
        auto b = a;
        a = nullopt;
        assert(!a && b);
    }
    // copy assignment
    {
        optional<std::string> a;
        optional<std::string> b{"foo"};
        optional<std::string> c{"bar"};
        a = b;
        assert(a == "foo");
        a = c;
        assert(a == "bar");
        static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<optional<Disabled>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<optional<Moveonly<>>>);
    }
    // move assignment
    {
        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<optional<Moveonly<>>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<
                      optional<Moveonly<false>>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_move_assignable_v<Disabled>);
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        optional<std::string> b{"bar"};
        b = std::move(a);
        assert(a == "" && b == "foo");
    }
    // single value assignment
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        a = "bar";
        static_assert(std::is_assignable_v<optional<std::string>&, const char*>);
        static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<optional<std::string>&, int>);
    }
    // converting copy assignment
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        optional<const char*> b{"bar"};
        a = b;
        assert(a == "bar");
        static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<optional<std::string>&,
                                            optional<int>&>);
    }
    // converting move assignment
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        optional<const char*> b{"bar"};
        a = std::move(b);
        assert(a == "bar" && b);
        static_assert(!std::is_assignable_v<optional<std::string>&, optional<int>>);
    }
    // emplace
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        optional<std::string> b{"bar"};
        a.emplace(5, 'a');
        assert(a == "aaaaa");
        a.emplace({'a', 'b', 'c'});
        assert(a == "abc");
        a.emplace(std::move(*b));
        assert(a == "bar" && b == "");
    }
    // swap, general
    {
        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<optional<Moveonly<>>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<optional<Moveonly<false>>>);
        static_assert(!std::is_swappable_v<optional<Disabled>>);
   }
    // swap, case one
    {
        optional<int> a{1}, b{2};
        a.swap(b);
        assert(a == 2 && b == 1);
        swap(a, b);
        assert(a == 1 && b == 2);
    }
    // swap, case two
    {
        optional<int> a{1}, b;
        a.swap(b);
        assert(!a && b == 1);
        swap(a, b);
        assert(a == 1 && !b);
    }
    // swap, case three
    {
        optional<int> a, b{2};
        a.swap(b);
        assert(a == 2 && !b);
        swap(a, b);
        assert(!a && b == 2);
    }
    // swap, case four
    {
        optional<int> a, b;
        a.swap(b);
        assert(!a && !b);
        swap(a, b);
        assert(!a && !b);
    }
    // observers
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        assert(a->size() == 3);
        assert(*a == "foo");
        assert(a);
        assert(a.has_value());
        assert(a.value() == "foo");
        assert(a.value_or("bar") == "foo");

        optional<std::string> b{*std::move(a)};
        assert(a == "");
        a = "foo";
        b = std::move(a).value();
        assert(a == "");
        a = "foo";
        b = std::move(a).value_or("bar");
        assert(a == "" && b == "foo");

        constexpr optional<std::pair<int, int>> c;
        static_assert(!c && !c.has_value());
        //　static_assert(c.value().first == 5); // throws bad_optional_access
        static_assert(c.value_or(std::pair(21, 42)) == std::pair(21, 42));
    }
    // reset
    {
        optional<std::string> a{"foo"};
        a.reset();
        assert(!a);
        a.reset();
        assert(!a);
    }
    // nullopt features
    {
        static_assert(std::is_empty_v<nullopt_t>);
        static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<nullopt_t>);
        static_assert(!std::is_aggregate_v<nullopt_t>);
    }
    // bad_optional_access
    {
        static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<bad_optional_access>);
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::exception, bad_optional_access> &&
                      std::is_convertible_v<bad_optional_access*, std::exception*>);
    }
    // comparison between optionals
    {
        constexpr optional<int> a{42}, b{21}, c;
        static_assert(a == a && !(a == b) && c == c && !(a == c) && !(c == a));
        static_assert(!(a != a) && a != b && !(c != c) && a != c && c != a);
        static_assert(!(a < a) && !(a < b) && !(c < c) && !(a < c) && c < a);
        static_assert(a <= a && !(a <= b) && c <= c && !(a <= c) && c <= a);
        static_assert(!(a > a) && a > b && !(c > c) && a > c && !(c > a));
        static_assert(a >= a && a >= b && c >= c && a >= c && !(c >= a));
    }
    // comparison with nullopt
    {
        constexpr optional<int> a{42};
        static_assert(!(a == nullopt || nullopt == a));
        static_assert(a != nullopt && nullopt != a);
        static_assert(!(a < nullopt) && nullopt < a);
        static_assert(!(a <= nullopt) && nullopt <= a);
        static_assert(a > nullopt && !(nullopt > a));
        static_assert(a >= nullopt && !(nullopt >= a));

        constexpr optional<int> b;
        static_assert(b == nullopt && nullopt == b);
        static_assert(!(b != nullopt || nullopt != b));
        static_assert(!(b < nullopt) && !(nullopt < b));
        static_assert(b <= nullopt && nullopt <= b);
        static_assert(!(b > nullopt) && !(nullopt > b));
        static_assert(b >= nullopt && nullopt >= b);
    }
    // comparison with T
    {
        constexpr optional<double> a{42.0};
        static_assert(a == 42 && 42 == a && !(a == 21) && !(21 == a));
        static_assert(!(a != 42) && !(42 != a) && a != 21 && 21 != a);
        static_assert(!(a < 42) && !(42 < a) && !(a < 21) && 21 < a);
        static_assert(a <= 42 && 42 <= a && !(a <= 21) && 21 <= a);
        static_assert(!(a > 42) && !(42 > a) && a > 21 && !(21 > a));
        static_assert(a >= 42 && 42 >= a && a >= 21 && !(21 >= a));

        constexpr optional<double> b;
        static_assert(!(b == 42) && !(42 == b));
        static_assert(b != 42 && 42 != b);
        static_assert(b < 42 && !(42 < b));
        static_assert(b <= 42 && !(42 <= b));
        static_assert(!(b > 42) && 42 > b);
        static_assert(!(b >= 42) && 42 >= b);
    }
    // make optional
    {
        constexpr int ans = 42;
        auto a = make_optional(ans);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), optional<int>>);
        assert(a == 42);

        constexpr auto b = make_optional<std::pair<double, double>>(ans, ans);
        static_assert(b == std::pair(42.0, 42.0));

        auto c = make_optional<std::vector<int>>({39, 42});
        assert((c == std::vector<int>{39, 42}));
    }
    // hash
    {
        assert(std::hash<optional<double>>{}(42) == std::hash<double>{}(42));

        using disabled = std::hash<optional<std::vector<double>>>;
        static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<disabled>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty good.  My comments are trivial nitpicking.

- The constructor of `struct in_place_t` gains nothing from `explicit` (it can't be considered as a conversion if it has no arguments).  Whilst `explicit` prevents users writing `in_place_t x = {}`, I certainly think that's a reasonable thing to want to do, and won't cause any *surprising* conversions.
- The comment `// [optional.comp.with.t], comparison with T` probably should read "comparison with value" or similar, given that the other argument is a `const U&`.
- <del>It shouldn't be necessary to provide `my_std::swap()`: providing member swap should be sufficient to allow `std::swap()` to work.</del>
- Instead of writing out the return type again in `make_optional`, we can simply use a brace-expression: `return {std::forward<T>(v)};`.  Sadly this won't work for the `in_place` overloads as that uses an `explicit` constructor.
- I'm not a fan of `else return false` in this:

  > ```
  >     if (x)
  >         return *x == v;
  >     else
  >         return false;
  > ```

  I'd probably rewrite as `return x && *x == v;`; similarly for all these related comparisons.
- I don't think there's a need for `static_cast<bool>` in the optional/optional comparisons, since the the arguments of logical operators are [contextually converted to `bool`](//stackoverflow.com/a/39995574/4850040).

Comment: Making the default constructor of `in_place_t` non-`explicit` allows code like `in_place_t ip = {};` which is ill-formed according to the standard.  The "comparison with T" is how the standard calls these function templates (which doesn't make much sense to me either).  Also, are you sure that `std::swap` calls the `swap` member function?  Otherwise, great review!

Comment: That's a good point about `explicit` that I hadn't appreciated before - thanks for educating me!  As for `swap`, I read "*The expected way to make a user-defined type swappable is to provide a non-member function swap in the same namespace as the type: see Swappable for details.*"  However, when I removed `my_std::swap()` and adding `using std::swap;` into the functions, I got a run-time assertion failure which I didn't probe further; I don't understand why there's a difference.

Comment: "... and adding `using std::swap;` into the functions" into which functions?

Comment: Into the test functions that call `swap()` (as indicated by compilation errors).

Comment: Maybe I just can't read - that definitely says ***non**-member `swap`* right there!  Sorry for that.

Comment: Actually, `= {}` *will* cause surprising conversions - it allows `{}` to match a function parameter of the tag type.